# Java Framework/pattern to modify value

Tags: java, java-8, expression, comparator

I have a Object Person

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer age ;
    private String address;
    private String group;
    private String id;

    public Person(String name, Integer age, String address, String group, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.group = group;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", group='" + group + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The meta data

```
public class MetaData {
    private String fieldName;
    private String comparator;
    private String fieldValue;
    private String newFieldName;
    private String newFieldValue;

    public MetaData(String fieldName, String comparator, String fieldValue, String newFieldName, String newFieldValue) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
        this.newFieldName = newFieldName;
        this.newFieldValue = newFieldValue;
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public String getComparator() {
        return comparator;
    }

    public void setComparator(String comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public String getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue;
    }

    public void setFieldValue(String fieldValue) {
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }

    public String getNewFieldName() {
        return newFieldName;
    }

    public void setNewFieldName(String newFieldName) {
        this.newFieldName = newFieldName;
    }

    public String getNewFieldValue() {
        return newFieldValue;
    }

    public void setNewFieldValue(String newFieldValue) {
        this.newFieldValue = newFieldValue;
    }
}
```

I get list of person . For each person I have to go through the metadata (based on the ID )
For each metadata I have to see which field to match and then what value to replae with

for example

```
public class TestPersonModifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new Person("John", 22, "London", "BETA", "ABC"));
        personList.add(new Person("Mathew", 44, "Glasgow", "ALPHA", "XYZ"));

        List<MetaData> metaData = new ArrayList<>();

        metaData.add(new MetaData("name", "EQUALS", "John", "group", "SIGMA"));
        metaData.add(new MetaData("name", "EQUALS", "Mathew", "address", "Singapore"));

        //g
        personList.forEach(p -> {

            metaData.forEach(m -> {

                if (m.getFieldName().equals("name")) {
                    if (m.getComparator().equals("EQUALS")) {

                        if (p.getName().equals(m.getFieldValue())) {

                            if (m.getNewFieldName().equals("group")) {

                                System.out.println(p.getId() + "::The group value changed from " + p.getGroup() + " to " + m.getNewFieldValue());
                                p.setGroup(m.getNewFieldValue());
                            }
                            if (m.getNewFieldName().equals("address")) {
                                System.out.println(p.getId() + "::The address value changed from " + p.getAddress() + " to " + m.getNewFieldValue());

                                p.setGroup(m.getNewFieldValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    }
}
```

As above it will be very clumsy as there will be more comparator operators and more field.

Is there expression language framework I can use or JAva library or any open soure framework to make it generic solution

Comment: People who vote question to be closed should care to comment.

Comment: [dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are happy with slightly less convenient form

```
import com.google.common.base.Equivalence;
...
metaData.add(new MetaData(Person.class, Equivalence.equals(), "name", "John", "group", "SIGMA"));
```

the simplest Java-only based solution is to add class of introspected instances into metadata, parameterize the way of comparing objects (I used Guava here, you can also use plain Java 8 `BiPredicate<T super Person>`) and specify names of properties.

When executed, you can utilize `java.beans.Introspector#getBeanInfo()` to discover getter and setter name (this is the safest way to get over various Java Beans freaks such as boolean properties, fully-capitalized property names etc. - I recommend to prefer it over halfbaked string-replacement-based tools) and invoke them accordingly.

You can further shorten the call using

```
metaData.add(new MetaData<Person>(Equivalence.equals(), "name", "John", "group", "SIGMA"));
```

(class can be derived using reflection hack known as type token or type literal)

or creating own subclass such as `EqualsMetadata` or `PersonMetadata`, you get the idea.

---

Alternatively, you can avoid (plain old) reflection at all and define everything with method references:

```
metaData.add(new MetaData(Equivalence.equals(), Person::getName, Person::setName, "John", Person::getGroup, Person::setGroup, "SIGMA"));
```

which is longer but typesafer - you can ensure the arguments `John` and `SIGMA` correspond with getter and setter type.

---

To realize it with external tool, I recommend to have a look on mapstruct.org. Dozer is also possible, however in our project we migrate to mapstruct due to performance and philosophy based on generated code which IMHO gives better insight what's really happening during conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly three pitfalls:

- First, you need some kind of mapping from the field name to the getter/setter method to access the field value from the POJO model class.
- Secondly, the data type of the individual field is different. So you need a different comparer if the field value does not implement `Comparable`. The types you used implement `Comparable`, so you are fine.
- Thirdly, Java cannot convert built-in value types from or to `Object` in a generic way; i.e. the signatures of getter methods do not match in general. You already avoided this one by choosing the boxed types for trivial data types like int.

To get all this working you need to take the following steps:

1. So in the first step you need to **build a repository of your getter methods**. I.e. something like `HashMap<String, Function<Person, Object>> map1`. You can do this statically by adding all getters explicitly by `map1.put("name", Person::getName)` or by reflection.
2. Next you need to **build a repository for the setters**. I.e. something like `HashMap<String, BiConsumer<Person, Object>> map2`. Again you can use reflection or explicit initialization. In the latter case there is another pitfall because the generic type conversion for the setter is no longer covariant. This can be by handled by a double unchecked cast:

   ```
   map2.put("name", (BiConsumer)(BiConsumer<Person, String>)Person::setName);
   ```

   Because of Javas type erasure all setters have in fact the same matching method signature.
3. Assuming that all your value types implement `Comparable` the next step is quite straight forward.
   Invoke your getter from the repository, compare the values (be aware of nulls) and apply the desired comparison operator (`= 0`, `< 0`, `> 0` or whatever) - btw.: you really should use an `enum` for `MetaData::comparator` instead of String.
4. Assign the resulting value if needed by invoking the setter from the repository.

If you do not require a String as key as filed name, you can join step 1 and step 2. Simply use the getter method reference as (strongly typed) key instead of the name. Now you need only *one* repository that maps from the getter to the setter. I.e.:

```
HashMap<Function<Person, Object>, BiConsumer<Person, Object>> map;
```

This maps from the getter (used as key) to the matching setter method.
I would prefer this way if desirable since strongly typed values are less error prone and more refactoring safe.